# Send SQLite Database as email

Tags: android

In my app I want to send the history stored in my SQLite databse via email to another person,
(i.e as there is an option in 'Whatsapp' to send user chat via email, as a text file).

So here I just want an approach how to begin with this problem.

Thanks

Comment: 1. function to send email.
2. function that get text from db
3. connect them togther

Comment: @amir for getting text from db do i have to create a text file and store it in sdcard somewhere and then attach it in email..(i.e using FileWriter) or there is another approach

Comment: i cant understand you sorry. you want to know how to use database or how to send mail?

Comment: It's what Amir says. You get your text from the database (maybe with a query?), then use an email intent to send it. Can't be that hard, can it? Unless you want to send the database as a whole, then you can just get the file from the ../database directory and send it as an attachment. Again, Amir sums it up nicely.

Comment: I got that what Amir is saying. I was just asking that for creating a text file from database do i have to run a query and save its content in text file using FileWriter ??...or there is another approach such as any APIs available??

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `EXTRA_STREAM` to your Intent that sends e-mail:

```
intent.setType("application/octet-stream");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(databaseFile));
```

Where **databaseFile** is your database file.

Don't forget that you need to copy your file on external storage because you cannot attach file(s) stored in application-package directory.

Whole code can looks like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"recipient@domain.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some message text");
i.setType("application/octet-stream");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(databaseFile));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send e-mail"));
```

If you want to put multiple attachements, you can use:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
...
ArrayList<Uri> items = new ArrayList<Uri>();
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(pathToFile));       
items.add(uri);
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, items);
```

**Note:** Same will work for txt files.

Comment: I want to send it as a text file not as database file so that reciever can read it directly. So do i have to create a text file and store it in sdcard somewhere and then attach it in email??

Comment: it will works also for txt files but you need to copy file on external storage.

Comment: For creating a text file from database do i have to run a query and save its content  in text file using FileWriter ??...or there is another approach??                                                                 thanks